# Adding icons to the task bar

Tags: taskbar

I no longer can add items to the task bar using either IE or Chrome. I recently installed a new graphics card. Could this have anything to do with the problem?
I was able to add internet items to the taskbar before but when I attempt to add something to the task bar I get this message "Unable to open this Internet Shortcut. The protocol 'ChromeHTML' does not have a registered program". I have assigned the default file associations required to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing OS version, I can't tell you much here.

For Windows 7 and up (I think?):
However have you tried making a shortcut to a website and then "pin to taskbar" after a rightclick on the shortcut?

For Windows Vista - XP:
Using the Quick Launch feature: Click the icon of the program you want to add (you can find most program icons on the Start menu or the desktop), and then drag it to the Quick Launch toolbar.

Note: If you don't see the Quick Launch toolbar, right-click an empty area of the taskbar, click Toolbars, and then click Quick Launch.

If neither of those helped you, then I am reading your question wrong in which case I have this:

Go to the "Start Menu".
Click on "Default Programs".
Click on "Associate a file type or protocol with a program".
Scroll to the "Protocols" section (bottom of the list).
Associate the program of choice with HTTP protocol.
[image]

Just a guess but I think this may fix your issue.
Last source used for HTTP association. [Seven Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/browsers-mail/232004-unable-open-website-shortcuts-desktop.html)